# Unable to show .DS_Store file on Mojave

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

I have scanned the web for my problem. Unable to find an answer.

It's impossible for me to see .DS_Store files in my Finder. I can see all other hidden files.

I'm on Mojave 10.14.3.

I have tried :

- Onyx;
- Terminal command (defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true);
- shift + cmd + .

I want to see .DS_Store files anywhere on my mac with the Finder, on the desktop, etc.

I'm able to see .DS_Store files with Atom and other softwares.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sorry, no. The "feature" was added in macOS 10.12 16A238m. Finder will no longer display .DS_Store files even with `com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` set.

If you go to `System Preferences and select Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services` and enable **"New Terminal at Folder"** you can open a terminal from the current Finder directory and do a `ls -a` however to find them.

Comment: Please tell how to open the located .DS_Store file?

Comment: Well that truly is a "feature" (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: @MohsinKhubaibAhmed type `cat .DS_Store` in Terminal to see its contents, or `open -a TextEdit .DS_Store` to open it in TextEdit